# Boundary effect of Graphics3D object Tube[]

Tags: graphics3d

I draw a Graphics3D object of two tubes:

```
Graphics3D[{Tube[{{-0.2, -1, 0}, {-0.2, 1, 0}}, 0.05], 
    Tube[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.05]}, Boxed -> False]
```

And I get this:

[image]

Now I want to have some edge effect of the two tubes, so that more parts of the back tube are excluded by the front tube, with the desired result like this:

[image]

Replacing `Tube[a_]` by `{EdgeForm[{White,Thick}],Tube[a]}` does not work, is there a simple way to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a tube around each of your tubes with a slightly bigger radius, transparent outer color, and white inner color.

```
t1 = Tube[{{-0.2, -1, 0}, {-0.2, 1, 0}}, 0.05];
t2 = Tube[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.05];

Graphics3D[{t1, t2, FaceForm[None, Glow[White]], 
   MapAt[1.8 # &, #, 2] & /@ {t1, t2}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. However, I have a new question based on your answer. If I replace the tube `t1` by an arrowed tube ``, then the `Faceform` does not apply to the arrowheads. For example, `t1 = {Arrowheads[{0.1}], Arrow[Tube[{{-0.2, -1, 0}, {-0.2, 1, 0}}, 0.05]]}; Graphics3D[{FaceForm[None, Glow[White]], t1}, Boxed -> False]` will leave the arrowhead visible. Why it does not apply to arrowhead?

Comment: @9527 Arrowhead for unknown reasons takes into account only regular color, not `FaceForm`. Try to play with `Cone[]`, it works well with `FaceForm`. You can also set it as a custom arrowhead (see [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Arrowheads.html)).

Answer (score 6):

ybeltukov's basic idea is certainly the way to go, but I think -- for easier general application -- it is a good idea to capture it into a function. So I would write

```
ghostTube[t_Tube, factor_?NumericQ] := 
  {FaceForm[None, Glow[White]], Tube[t[[1]], factor t[[2]]]}
```

and apply it like this

```
Module[{t1, t2},
  t1 = Tube[{{-0.2, -1, 0}, {-0.2, 1, 0}}, 0.05]; 
  t2 = Tube[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 0.05];
  Graphics3D[{t1, t2, ghostTube[#, 1.5] & /@ {t1, t2}}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: tubes.png]