# Adapting KnotDiagramData to form more visually pleasing diagram

Tags: graphics, knots

`Graphics[KnotData[{5, 1}, "KnotDiagramData"]]` gives

[image]

but I would like to create diagrams like this

[image]

remeniscent of Celtic knot designs (which I made by adapting the above *Mathematica* image in Illustrator). Is there any way to do this in *Mathematica* directly?

Comment: Realted: [How can I draw the Olympic rings with Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8885/4678)

Comment: Hey Martin: It's not Mathematica, but check out the [KnotPlot](http://www.knotplot.com/) site for everything knotical.

Comment: @KennyColnago great stuff - thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a common 3D trick with double boundary ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98043/4678), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48192/4678), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35333/4678)):

```
fun = KnotData[{5, 1}, "SpaceCurve"];
ParametricPlot3D[fun[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
   Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0, -1, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}] /. 
  Line[pts_] :> {White, Tube[pts, 0.1], FaceForm[Opacity[0], Black], 
    Tube[pts, 0.12]}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution thanks! :) One minor poit - mine is showing up slightly differently to youur - ie with [contour lines](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ymcDq.png) - I an on v.10.2 - can you relpicate this?

Comment: @martin It is a bug of versions 10.0 – 10.2, I advise to upgrade to 10.3.

Comment: ok will do - thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

This is only a first idea how one could proceed

```
KnotData[{5, 1}, "Name"]
```

> "Solomon seal knot"

```
fun = KnotData["Solomon seal knot", "SpaceCurve"];

par =
 ParametricPlot3D[fun[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  Axes -> False,
  Boxed -> False,
  ViewPoint -> Above,
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.05]]
```

[image]

```
ColorNegate @ EdgeDetect @ Image @ par
```

[image]