# How to add an outline around a closed 3D surface?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, output

I would like to add a black outline (silhouette) all around a closed surface.  Here's a MWE code to work with :

```
Manipulate[
    SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, t, 2Pi + t},
        Mesh -> {7, 7},
        MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[2, 5],
        PlotRange -> All,
        Boxed -> False,
        Axes -> None,
        SphericalRegion -> True,
        Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
        ImageSize -> {500, 500}
    ],
    {{t, 0, Style["t", 10]}, 0, 2Pi, 0.01}
]
```

So is it possible to draw a thin line all around that sphere, to make it standing out of the white background ?

**EDIT :**  By "outline" (or "silhouette", or "profile"), I mean some curve like the circle around the ball shown below (the outline should be made for any surface, not just for the sphere defined in the code above !)

[image: a sphere with an outline]

The outline should be drawn around the whole surface's exterior, and don't apply to parts inside the surface (except if it has holes).

Comment: An incredibly stupid and impractical hack that works in this case (of a perfect sphere) would be adding a `Prolog -> Inset[Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 300]]]` as an option. Some sort of `Inset` solution might actually be of use even on the final solution.

Comment: BTW, can you clarify if you want to have this outline only between the background and the object, or possibly also between the object and parts of itself it occludes?

Comment: If you draw a black outline around the whole surface of the sphere, you will not be able to see the sphere.

Comment: @bills Heh heh, being overly pedantic... :)

Comment: @bills, LOL !  Ok, I'll edit the question, to precise the idea of a "silhouette".

Comment: It will be hard to make responsive general solution, here's something closely related: [Sketch-type graphics with transparency and dashed hidden lines?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45410/5478)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believed that there are some standard options in Mathematica to do this.

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99452/484

Comment: Can Mathematica drop a **shadow** under (or behind) a 3D surface ?

Comment: About the drop shadow idea : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-make-a-drop-shadow-for-a-graphics3d-objects

Comment: @Cham could you comment on what doesn't work for you in the solution presented in [How to make a drop-shadow for a Graphics3D objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/938/27951), the post you mentioned above?

Comment: @MarcoB, I'm giving up the outline idea because it will certainly not work with my old version 7, or it will have a very high impact on performances under a Manipulate box.  The shadow codes don't work for me.

Comment: Highlighting the edge of a sphere or other arbitrary and possibly smooth object is a problem (well, not really a problem, just a convention) of engineering graphics/drafting/sketching. I would suggest to all would be answerers to consider the problem from their standpoint. When these people draw 3D representations of objects they design, they do not think of their drawing as a 3D image. On the contrary, they are constructing a certain **projection** of a 3D object onto a 2D plane. A sphere always becomes a circle, and thus has a well defined boundary.

Comment: The only additional solid lines are then those, that are captured by the `EdgeForm` function. @Kuba is spot on with his related linking, and I don't think there's much to add to that, but another possible approach would indeed be to construct projections of `Graphics3D` scenes onto planes.

Answer (score 3):

Although, this may not be the best answer. I thought I post it for fun.

**Input:**

```
core = {Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1.9]};
outline = {Yellow, Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 2]};

Graphics3D @ {core, outline}
```

**Output:**

[image: output example]

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you could probably mess around with lighting property. Here is an example:

```
sphere1 = Graphics3D[core, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}];
sphere2 = Graphics3D[outline];

Show[sphere1, sphere2]
```

And the output of this would be something like:

[image: output2]

**EDIT:**

Some additional way how to modify edges:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
    FaceForm[White], #}] & /@ {Cuboid[], 
  Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}
```

With the associated output:

[image: output 3]

**Reference:**

[Sphere](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sphere.html)
[Graphics3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html?q=Graphics3D)
[Opacity](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html?q=Opacity)

Comment: What would you do if you want a black outline ?  The transparency trick will not work in this case.  You may have to duplicate the surface, one in full black, behind the normal surface, but then there will be a problem of intersection and depth sorting...

Comment: I am afraid my WPL skills aren't at that level to deliver what you've requested in your original post. The only reason why I've added this solution is to share my ideas in relation to your question.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what is WPL ?

Comment: Wolfram programming language

Comment: The last edit appears to be highly interesting.  I don't have access to Mathematica right now, and I can't wait to try this code (**EdgeForm** and **FaceForm**).

Comment: What are the differences between **FaceForm**, **EdgeForm** and **Mesh** ?

Comment: @Cham The names should speak for themselves, shouldn't they? `FaceForm` passes directives to the *sides* of the cube, the big squares from which it is assembled, `EdgeForm`, well, acts on the edges... I really can't come up with a synonym for them. `EdgeForm` is really what you're looking for, but unfortunately in MMA it seems to work only on sharp corners, like those of a polyhedron. If it's a smooth surface, like the edge of a sphere then there aren't any explicit edges to highlight.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, what I don't understand is that any surface in MMA are made of polygons, with an edge.  So for the moment (I still don't have access to MMA right now), I don't see what FaceForm and EdgeForm could do, relative to Mesh.

Comment: @Cham I don't think `Mesh` is too related here. Not any surface is polygonal in MMA. `Graphics3D[Sphere[]]//InputForm` returns `Graphics3D[Sphere[{0,0,0}]]` so it doesn't have edges. PS my bad, the entire surface of the sphere is regarded as a face though.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, a MMA sphere is still made of lots of small triangles.  The polygonal shape can easily be seen at close range.  I guess I'll have to try the FaceForm and EdgeForm later, to understand what they do.

Comment: @Cham that may be how MMA renders it, but it does not regard a sphere as a set of polygons. `EdgeForm` does not influence anything about `Sphere[]`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, so if you try to use FaceForm and EdgeForm on a surface defined by some smooth functions, what do you get ?  Take for example the surface {Sin[theta]Cos[phi], Sin[theta]Sin[phi], Cos[theta]} (a sphere in parametric plot, not as a MMA primitive).  What would you get ?

Comment: @Cham yes, *that* will be a collection of polygons with the expected behavior of `EdgeForm`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, could you try it and add it to your answer ?  EdgeForm and FaceForm to a sphere in parametric form ?